# Beamer: itemize in presentation mode with lemma duplicates slide

Tags: beamer, theorems, itemize

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Next up a lemma.
    \item \begin{lemma}A lemma.\end{lemma}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would expect to get a pdf file with two pages, but the first page is duplicated and in fact I receive three pages.

What can I do? I noticed that

```
\item Something: \begin{lemma}A lemma.\end{lemma}
```

is split up across two slides, so `<+->` might interfere with `lemma`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to omit the second `\item`. In your example, this seems the right option to me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item Next up a lemma.
      \begin{lemma}A lemma.\end{lemma}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you need the `\item` (e.g. for the `\item Something` case), you can explicitly override the overlay increment for the `lemma`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item Next up a lemma.
      \item Something
      \begin{lemma}<.->A lemma.\end{lemma}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Answer 1 is not perfect, since I want multiple theorems numbered (my `itemize` is in fact an `enumerate`, I oversimplified my MWE). So I can't (don't want to) omit the `\itemize`. Answer 2 is JUST what I need. Perfect!